# How to serialize a function from a model class that has @property decorator in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using django_rest framework and I would like to know how do I serialize a function that has a @property decorator. In this case from the code below I have `total_salary`

```
class SalaryDetail(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                choices=MONTH_CHOICES)

    basic = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    da = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    hra = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    allowance = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    loss_of_pay = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    repayment_of_loan = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def total_salary(self):
        return self.basic + self.da + self.hra + self.allowance
```

I know that in the `serializers.py` I will start by doing something like this:

```
class SalaryDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model: SalaryDetail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `IntegerField()` with read_only set to true,

```
class SalaryDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_salary = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SalaryDetail
        fields = ('total_salary',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is, define a `SerializerMethodField()` as below,

```
class SalaryDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_salary = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_salary(self, model):
        return model.total_salary()

    class Meta:
        model = SalaryDetail
        fields = ('total_salary',)
```

Comment: when I implement `POST` or a `GET` request how do I make it possible to see the total_salary? Ordinarily when one doesn't have calculation definitions  in a model class the implementation is easy an example would be :                                                                        
    queryset = Salary.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SalaryDetailSerializer